# Looking for an application which alerts about new questions under a particular topic

Tags: support, questions, app-request, linux

I've installed [StackApplet](https://launchpad.net/stackapplet), but it only tracks the reputation of a particular user.

Is there an application which tracks new questions under a particular topic, and notifies (in system tray) when there is a new one? I'm using Linux Mint.

Comment: If a browser app/userscript is an option for you, take a look at [this script](http://stackapps.com/questions/4352/real-time-questions-for-stack-exchange).