# Real time questions for any Stack Exchange site

Tags: script, questions, greasemonkey, bookmarklet, tampermonkey

### Screenshot / Code Snippet

[image: Real-time Screenshot]

### About

This script provides real time updates and filtering of active questions for all SE sites.

- Shows active questions in real time
- Filter by favorite tags
- Filter by question
- Erase seen questions (By clicking link or keypress <kbd>e</kbd>)

#### License

Released under the [MIT Open Source License](http://www.opensource.org/licenses/mit-license.php).

#### Download

Hosted on: <strike>userscripts.org</strike> [userscripts-mirror.org](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/179215) <kbd>[Install now](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/source/179215.user.js)</kbd>

#### Platform

Google Chrome

Install the [Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo?hl=en) plugin. Afterwards click the "install now" link above.

Firefox

Install the [Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/en/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) plugin. Afterwards click the "install now" link above.

Any Browser (Bookmarklet)

Create a bookmark using the following code snippet as location:

```
javascript:(function(){document.body.appendChild(document.createElement('script')).src='http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/source/179215.user.js';})();
```

Afterwards browse to /questions on any SE site and click that new bookmark.

### Release notes

- *Oct 5, 2013* Initial Version
- *Oct 6, 2013* Added support to run as bookmarklet

### Contact

This script is created by [jgb](https://stackapps.com/users/22584/jgb). You can just leave feedback in the comments, or answer below. <strike>or create an issue on [userscripts.org](http://userscripts-mirror.org/scripts/show/179215).</strike>